# Is there a way to find out whether a class is a direct base of another class?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, metaprogramming

I'm wondering whether there is a way to find out whether a class is a direct base of another class i.e. in Boost type trait terms a `is_direct_base_of` function. As far as I can see, Boost doesn't seem to support this kind of functionality, which leads me to think that it's impossible with the current C++ standard.

The reason I want it is to do some validation checking on two macros that are used for a reflection system to specify that one class is derived from another, as in the example code below.

header.h:

```
#define BASE     A
#define DERIVED  B

class A {};
class B : public A 
{
   #include <rtti.h>
};
```

rtti.h:

```
// I want to check that the two macro's are correct with a compile time assert
Rtti<BASE, DERIVED> m_rtti;
```

Although the macros seem unnecessary in this simple example, in my real world scenario `rtti.h` is a lot more complex.

One possible avenue would be to compare the size of the this pointer with the size of a this pointer cast to the base type and somehow trying to figure out whether it's the size of the base class itself away or something. (Yeah, you're right, I don't know how that would work either!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked myself, "What C++ constructs do differentiate between direct inheritance vs. indirect?"  It comes to mind that C++ constructors of derived types directly call constructors for their direct base(s) only.  So code like this:

```
Derived::Derived() : Base() {}
```

Is only valid if `Base` is is a direct base of `Derived`.  And since you are injecting the code of `rtti.h` into the body of `Derived`, you can tolerate the restriction that this technique is only directly visible within the derived class itself (i.e. it is not as general as a hypothetical `type_traits::is_direct_base_of`, but does not need to be).

So since we probably don't want to mess around with the default constructors per se, how about adding some special-purpose ones?

```
#define BASE     A
#define DERIVED  B

struct rtti_tag {}; // empty type

class A
{
protected:
    A(rtti_tag) { assert(false); } // never actually called
};

#include <rtti.h>
class B : public A
{
    IS_DIRECT_BASE_OF(DERIVED, BASE); // fails to compile if not true
};
```

`rtti.h`:

```
#define IS_DIRECT_BASE_OF(_B_, _A_) _B_(rtti_tag tag) : _A_(tag) \
    { assert(false); } // never actually called
```

This code compiles for me with g++ 4.2; if I insert a new class in the inheritance hierarchy, the assertion breaks and compilation fails with what I think is a reasonably descriptive diagnostic:

```
In constructor ‘B::B(rtti_tag)’:
error: type ‘A’ is not a direct base of ‘B’
...
```

Comment: `Derived::Derived() : Base() {}` is also valid if `Base` is a non-direct virtual base class -- possibly that case could be eliminated with (yet another) test?  +1 anyway.

Comment: Good point, j_random_hacker, that's pretty clever (or evil!).  I don't know offhand how to fix this "problem," but hopefully it's enough of a pathological thing that it doesn't really need to be addressed (C++ being a language where the ill-intentioned can make a mess of almost anything).

Comment: I agree, it's a pathological case that you don't need to lose sleep over. I thought of it because I once saw a trick to prevent further derivation from a class (i.e. force it to be a "leaf") that was also subverted by virtual inheritance. VI is really a bit of a language design hack -- e.g. a virtual base class's `operator=()` will be called an unspecified number of times when an object of derived class is assigned to.